# instantiate a object from a .class deployed in a ear of other project?

Tags: java, jboss

I have 2 projects, which each one has it's ear deployed on jboss.

I wanna know if there is any way (without changing buildpath) of instantiate an object of a class from project 2 in my project 1.

So, there is a class deployed on ear 2. I want my project 1 to initialize an object of the class on ear 2 only by the class name. This class name should be in a .properties file which is also deployed on ear 2. So my project 1 must somehow get the properties file only using its name. And the same for the class written on the .properties.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is communication between the two applications necessary? I.e. is it mandatory that it is ear2 that knows which class will be instanciated and instanciate it itself before communicating it to ear1 ? If it's not, you will probably want to extract your common code to a jar, then make your two projects depend on it (either at the build level, or at the server level by using a module to contain your jar).

Comment: That's one way to go but i was wondering if there is another way of getting a deployed class without any dependencies. What you said would be my second option.

Comment: Technically, both applications have their distinct classloaders with their own classpath, and you need your classloader to know the definition of a class before you can instantiate it. Although there would be others, the simplest clean solution is to include those classes in both applications' classpath.